# ros-groovy-pcl problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed pcl in ubuntu with command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pcl
```

When I try compile the example of tutrial I have the nex error:

```
openni_grabber.h no such file or directory
```

I look in io folder and the library openni_grabber isn't.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61872/ros-groovy-pcl-problem/) by [aps40](https://answers.ros.org/users/4500/aps40/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that standalone pcl will collide with ros_pcl and anything build on top of it.  You may have better luck with pcl17 http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-05-03**:
You are right. I am currently using Fuerte as well as Groovy. My answer works on Fuerte as it has PCL version 1.5.

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2014-03-18**:
@Tfoote, Henmu: the better way to install both pcl and ros is using pcl17? it looks complicated in pcl17 page whereas the installation of pcl (at pointcloud.org) and ros normal install is straightforward. Is there any other way to fix this collision?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-03-18**:
If you use newer versions of ROS it uses pcl 1.7. Moving large systems takes time and we need to make sure to provide stability to our users. In Hydo we package pcl 1.7. In Indigo it will use the upstream version.

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2014-05-10**:
@tfoote : I was just trying to resolve the collision between standalone opencv library and the one provided by ROS. I came across a idea of creating my own 'Find***.cmake' for the standalone library file. Do you think it can help to prevent the collision even if pcl_ros and standalone pcl are of same version but different installation paths?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-10**:
@Hemu you can try, but I don't think that's the biggest problem. I expect by jumping versions around you're going to run into actual differences in the code, not just packaging issues. Both can be found adaquately, but they cannot be used simultaneously due to collisions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem so I used standalone pcl library. I compiled PCL from source and added the following lines to CMakeLists.txt in the package (remember to create a package that does not depend on pcl_ros):

```
find_package(PCL 1.6 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}) 
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

rosbuild_add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I successfully executed some of the examples.
If your purpose is to execute pcl tutorial examples, then you do not need to create a ROS package. However, if your purpose is to view the pcl data you can use the following procedure:

```
1. roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
2. convert sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 data to pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>
3. Then create a pcl::visualization::CloudViewer object to view the pcl::PointCloud data.
```

In this case you will not need OpenNIGrabber.

---

Originally posted by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) with karma: 156 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-04-30**:
To compile PCL from source: http://pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html